# What is the scope of load tag in Django templates?

Tags: django-templates

What is the scope of custom tags loaded using [load](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#load) in django templating system especially w.r.t Template Inheritance?

How can you effectively load the same custom tag in a tree of template hierarchy. I couldn't find either of the info in docs. Any pointers would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is, it's limited to template file irrespective of inheritance.

Answer (score 7):

I also wondered about this and found the documentation lacking, so I decided to do some testing on my own.

As of django 1.4, the answer is: **the scope of a loaded custom tag is limited strictly to the file it is loaded in (using `{% load %}`) and absolutely nothing else**.

The following attempts to use a custom tag have failed:

- Template A `extend`s Template B:

  - Load in A and attempt to use in B
  - Load in A and attempt to use in B inside a block
  - Load in a block in A and attempt to use in same block in B, with or without super
- Template A `include`s Template B:

  - Load in A and attempt use in B
  - Load in A and attempt to pass into B explicitly using `with context`
- Template A including Template B using `{% ssi ... parsed %}

  - Load in A and attempt to use in B

So yeah, it is strictly a per-file thing (which is good because it makes it impossible to squirrel in mystery  tags from a distance - unless of course you do so on purpose by messing with the global loader (which you shouldn't))

Comment: Good tests! It definitely prevents mystery tags but so is the case with javascript code that might be coming from super-super-super block and you'll have to track through multiple templates to find it :-)